# EF6 table-per-type: does is matter if the base class is abstract or not?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

we have imlemented a class hierarchy with one base class and 10 classes directly deriving from that base class.

With the help of `EF6` and `table-per-type`, we save the data to `SqlServer`.

The queries which are generated are HUGE, so we are investigating our `poco` model, and in most code examples I see the baseclass is abstract.

Ours is not, so I wondered if it makes any difference, from a EF point of view?

Comment: As far as I know it does not make any difference in TPT in terms of tables in SQL server; but if it was TPC (table per concrete type) abstract classes would not map to SQL tables.